# error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(int&, Quest*)'

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I get this weird error in g++; it compiles fine in Visual Studio.

```
struct Quest
{
    static map<int, Quest*> Cache;
};

Quest *Quest::LoadFromDb(BaseResult& result, int *id)
{
    Quest *ret;
    if(result.Error())
    {
        if(id)
            Cache.insert(make_pair<int, Quest*>(*id, NULL)); // <--- Problematic line

        return NULL;
    }

// ...
}
```

Exact error:

> DataFilesStructure.cpp:9135:58: error: no matching function for
>   call to   'make_pair(int&, Quest*)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does it work with an explicit cast?

```
if (id)
    Cache.insert(make_pair<int, Quest*>(int(*id), NULL));
```

Also, a cpp file with 9000 lines, really?

Comment: It's automatically generated, and yes, int() seems to fix it!!

Comment: What actually has happened here? We have an explicit template function instance `make_pair<int,Quest*)(int, Quest*)` and it's called with arguments of types `int&` and either `int` or `void*`. Then: `int&` is implicitly convertible to `int` and `NULL` may or may not be implicitly convertible to `Quest*`, depending on the definition *(don't use NULL in C++, NULL is in C!)*. Anyway, my question is: How COULD an explicit cast of FIRST argument fix the problem?

Comment: @Kos: I'm not certain, it probably has to do with the fact that `*id` is an *lvalue* while `int(*id)` is an *rvalue*, but this is more of a gut feeling :)

Comment: OK, I needed to check, I don't buy it :). On my GCC 4.5.1: `make_pair<int, Class*>(*p, 0);` where `p` is `int*` compiles w/o warnings, but does NOT compile when I supply a `void*` instead of `int` as the second parameter - **irregardless** if I pass `int` or `int&` as the first - as expected. How come this fixed the matter for the OP on GCC? @Krevan, admit it :) - you changed NULL to 0 or you changed the includes so that your NULL got redefined by another header to 0... it HAS to be something else! I doubt that we've just discovered a GCC bug...

Answer (score 20):

You are most probably using the C++0x version of the libstdc++ library. C++0x declares `make_pair` as

```
template <class T1, class T2>
pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y) noexcept;
```

If `T1` is `int`, then `x` is `int&&`, and therefor cannot take lvalues of type `int`. Quite obviously, `make_pair` is designed to be called without explicit template arguments

```
make_pair(*id, NULL)
```

Comment: @Krevan    If I have an integer variable i.
I want to make pair with i and another object. How exactly should I call makepair. 1) make_pair<*i, obj> 2) int&& j = i; make_pair<j, obj>? Both are not working. Whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: For make_pair in C++11 when you specify V1, V2 explicitly, there is no type deduction and arguments x and y are required to be rvalue. But if you don't specify V1, V2, type deduction happens, x and y do not need to be rvalue.

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove the template parameters:

```
Cache.insert(make_pair(*id, NULL));
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: This helped me. C++11 doesn't require the template params.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not a `Quest*` -- it may be being defined as ((void *)0) somewhere, which is not implicitly convertible to `Quest*`. Use `static_cast<Quest*>(0)` instead.

Comment: It's not but it can be converted to one, `Quest *a = NULL` for example.. And I explicitly list the template parameters. Anyways I tried, same error.

Comment: @Krevan: No, it is possible that it *cannot* be converted to one.

Comment: @Billy: Isn't `NULL` defined to be `0` in C++?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Normally yes, but it's possible for it to be redefined by a C library expecting `((void *)0)`.

Comment: @Billy: I see. Looking forward to C++0x's `nullptr` even more :)

Comment: I would really like the downvoter to explain him/herself so that I can fix the answer if it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

If a `NULL` value is need for the 2 value, maybe an explicit type conversion is needed:

```
return make_pair((node)NULL,(node)NULL); // NULL value
return make_pair((node *)NULL,(node *)NULL); // NULL pointer value
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be coming a bit late for you guys but could be useful for others.

Had exactly the same problem:

```
strVar= ...
newNode= ...
static map<string, Node*> nodes_str;
nodes_str.insert(make_pair(strVar, newNode)); // all OK
```

to

```
intVar= ...
newNode= ...
static map<int, Node*> nodes_int;
nodes_int.insert(make_pair(intVar, newNode)); // compile error
```

solved it by adding:

```
using std::make_pair;
```